# Crash when inflating a layout that sets the TextView.TextColor

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, textview, layout-inflater

I cannot inflate a layout if that layout sets the textColor of a TextView to the following...

```
android:textColor="?android:attr/textColor"
```

I believe that the value is definitely defined for the application because I have a drawable that also references this resource and it works just fine. But if I try and use the accent color instead then it will work fine, e.g.

```
android:textColor="?android:attr/colorAccent"
```

What is different about the textColor value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have to *assume* you are looking for the *primary* text color of your theme, thus you would use:

```
android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
```

There are a dozen or so `textColorXXXX` attributes, so you would need to review them to see which one you are actually trying to use.